# Flow player load the full video first, then playing. it not buffer the video like youtube

Tags: flowplayer

My code is :

```
   <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" Visible="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        RepeatColumns="2" CellSpacing="5">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <u>
                <%# Eval("Name") %></u>
            <hr />
            <a class="player data-embed=false" preload="true" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; display: block" href='<%# Eval("Id", "FileCS.ashx?Id={0}") %>'>
            <img
    src=""
    alt="Search engine friendly content" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; background-image:url('img/sales.jpg');" />
            </a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    <script src="FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        flowplayer("a.player", "FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
            plugins: {
                pseudo: { url: "FlowPlayer/flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.12.swf" }
            },
            clip: { provider: 'pseudo', autoPlay: false , autoBuffering: true},
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add  autoBuffering: true

have a look http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/configuration/